# Lighthouse - UPnP not available

Tags: lighthouse

I'm running Lighthouse beacon chain on Ubuntu and get `UPnP not available` on startup.

What is this dependent on? Is this some OS configuration? How to turn UPnP on?

Comment: UPnP is protocol that is managed by the router/bridge, a firewall may filter packets so check that too.

Comment: I have this same issue. Did you ever figure out the combination? Geth on the same box uses UPnP just fine.

Comment: No, I just forwarded ports in my router